# PHP XMLReader PCDATA invalid Char

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I'm parsing an feed which comes in from the web and get the following error code:

```
XMLReader::read(): http://myfeedurl:22180: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 16
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Do I need to declare anything?

Comment: Notify the Feed Provider about the broken XML and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Or suppress errors, then the error will be gone ;)

Comment: Mhm, don't think that this is possible, too large company :D Any other possibilities for me to fix this? I used SimplePie before, they managed it to report a warning but the script won't crash. Now I switched to my own implementation using XMLReader and was that exited about the speed, would really appreciate to at least copy SimplePie's behaviour!

Comment: @Tim broken XML is broken. You can try calling [`libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE)`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) before loading the feed, but the best solution would be to fix it on the feed's end.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that :) Sadly there isn't really a possibility for me to repair the xml generation serverside. Couldn't it be anything else? It seems a little strange to me that the mentioned company serves broken feeds, maybe special chars or anything?

Comment: @Tim the error message suggests it's an invalid character, so you might want to check with the XML. chr(16) is probably out of the allowed range of utf-8 characters. Can you provide the XML or feed URL you are trying to parse?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/es/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=300/genre=6014/xml

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses by the way! :)

Comment: Doesn't really seem to be my fault, even Google's Chrome fails with following error message above the content (which is displayed unformatted btw!): error on line 20972 at column 23: PCDATA invalid Char value 16

Comment: When I'm using libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE) it only seems to simplify the error code I'm recieving, the actual problem isn't solved (XMLReader::read(): An Error Occured while reading). So I ran a check with the corresponding feed url at W3C, perhaps you can take a look at it: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fes%2Frss%2Ftopfreeapplications%2Flimit%3D300%2Fgenre%3D6014%2Fxml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score -1):

have you ever tried simplexml? http://php.net/simplexml

PCDATA: Parsed Character DATA

CDATA: Character DATA

Comment: won't be fast enough, I definitely need to parse it on the fly